# Decompose a graph to its strongly connected components while not using an edge and its reverse

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

I know using tarjan's algorithm one can find the strongly connected components of a graph. I would like to define a strongly connected component in a slightly different way than normal and still be able to find the strongly connected components.

If $e = (u_1, u_2)$ is an edge I define $r(e)$ to be $(u_2, u_1)$. Then i define that 2 nodes $u, v$ are in the same strongly connected component if there is a cycle $C$ containing $u, v$ such that $\forall e \in C \: r(e) \notin C$ or in words a cycle that does not contain an edge and its reverse edge.

Is there a way of altering tarjan's algorithm (or any other algorithm) to use this definition of strongly connected components?

Comment: Are you requiring $C$ to be a cycle (with no repeated vertices) or merely a closed walk (so something like $(u,a,b,v,a,c,u)$ would be fine)?

Comment: Both would be interesting for me. But in the question I mean that an edge is not used twice but a vertex can be used twice. The other definition would be that 2 vertices are in the same component if there is a simple cycle connecting them (with no repeated vertices)